Last digit of some numbers
It is a common simple Olympiad exercise to show that we can find a suitable powers of $2$ that is starts in any string of digits base $10$, we can extend this problem to other powers of $b$ with the only condition being $10^k \neq b^l$. The proof for this fact is elementary, we only need that $(\{k \log_{10}(b)\})_{k}$ is dense on $[0, 1]$, so we can impose that there's $k$ such that $\log_{10}(n - \epsilon) < \{k \log_{10}(b)\} < \log_{10}(n + \epsilon)$ for some small $\epsilon$ and exponentiation in both sides wields the result. This method in general extends easily to any sequence of numbers that is also dense in $[0, 1]$, for example this also works well for $n!$, as it can be seen here that $\{n!\}$ is dense.
It is a bit natural to wonder how the problem changes when take the last digits instead, the problem for powers of $b$ seems less interesting as apparently we can simply work out some classifications on what the last digits can be, however if we take $n!$ and delete the rightmost $0$s, can we have the last digits remaining being any string of digits? For example, we can show that the last digit of a multiple of $2$ appears in some $n!$ (after deleting the $0$s rightmost, and this is just a casework), of course, we can't find any $n!$ that has the last digits $14$, in fact, the last digits would need to be a multiple of $4$. but any string of two digits divisible by $4$ appears for some $n \le 100$, as I checked here. I conjectured then

Given any multiple of $2^k$, we can find $n$ such that the $k$ rightmost non-zero digits of $n!$ corresponds to that multiple

which is a quite surprising result for me if it is true. If someone can give a solution or heuristics on why this should be true or counterexample to this problem I would be grateful.
